# Browsers cookie problem

Tags: python, browser, cookies

Well,

Opera and Chrome add 2 hours to expiration where i only want 15 minutes to be added. Actually they are both successful at that 15 minutes part but because of some reasons i didn't understand yet, they also add another 2 hours to date.

Here is response header:

```
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Thu, 28 Apr 2011 15:59:27 GMT
Server:lighttpd/1.4.28
Set-Cookie:SID=2554373e-9144-34af-b9ad-a67b2ccdc8cd; expires=Thu, 28 Apr 2011 16:14:27 GMT; Path=/
Thu, 28 Apr 2011 16:14:27 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

this is also fine. Exact date that i want. But when i check from browsers cookie list, I see `expires=Thu, 28 Apr 2011 18:14:27 GMT`.

What can cause that?
Thanks

Edit: Info:

To create cookie I use python. They all depend on server time which is same for all.
And all browsers are tested in same environment.

Edit Code Sample:

```
def createCookie(self):
    expiration = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=0,minutes=15)
    self.cookie['SID'] = self.SID
    self.cookie['SID']['path'] = "/"
    self.cookie['SID']['Expires'] = expiration.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT")
```

Comment: You’re using the wrong format; it needs to be `%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S GMT`.

Comment: Did not work. Still the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are not posting the related code to your question it is impossible to say what is causing the issue.

But my nose tells me you are probably mixing timezones in your time delta code.

Here is some info when dealing with timezone aware time and datetime objects in Python:

http://blog.mfabrik.com/2008/06/30/relativity-of-time-shortcomings-in-python-datetime-and-workaround/